# How it does work

Tags: grammar

Original sentence:

> Everyone agrees on how it works.

I would like to know if in the sentence:

> Everyone agrees on how it **does** work.

sounds okay. (In this case, ‘does’ is used to give extra force to the verb *work.*)

Comment: Different implications.

Comment: You mean two sentences above have different meanings? What do you mean by different implications?

Answer (score 2):

No, "Everyone agrees on how it does work" is not acceptable unless "does" has strong contrastive stress.  And, if "does" has contrastive stress, there must be something in the context that explains the contrast.  Perhaps someone has indicated that it doesn't work, so that there is the contrast between "doesn't work" and "DOES work".

Comment: I understood what you mean. Thank you so much about your kindness.

Comment: A machine may do work and everyone agrees on how it does that.